# Dynamically add a function to for a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I use an inline editor for bootstrap that needs to be initiate in the javascript.

I want to use a general class "editable" for elements but there is a problem when i use jQuery.load.

If i declare $('.editable').editable(); it works but when i load some content from external file with jQuery.load it doesn't work for elements inside loaded div.

I need to run $('.editable').editable(); again to make it works.

How can i assign the function to the class and work dynamically?

Thanks

Comment: you can't... there is no event delegation equivalent for this....

Comment: Agreed with @Arun , the new DOM elements need to be delegated to event   after they are loaded!

Comment: So i need to run the code every time i load the content? Or there is a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can run a function when AJAX events complete:

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/

If you run  `$('.editable').editable();` in that callback, should work.

For example:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  $('.editable').editable();
});
```

Comment: That's a good way! But again, if i add a div with that class with prepend/append it doesn't work since ajaxComplete works only on ajax requests.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found a way, not a clean one!

The Editable plugin adds a class "editable-click".
I made a listener on hover and if doesn't have that class to run the function on the element.

The final code:

```
$('body').on('mouseover', '.editable', function(event) {
    if( !$(this).hasClass('editable-click') )
        $(this).editable();
});
```